# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buying') in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reduce, redux-toolkit

**Index.js**
as You can see here the actions and store are being imported

```
> const store=require('./app/store')
> const cakeActions=require('./feature/cake/cakeSlice').cakeActions
> const icecreamActions=require('./feature/cake/cakeSlice').icecreamActions
> 
> console.log("Initial State",store.getState())
> const unsubscribe=store.subscribe(()=>{
> console.log('Updated State',store.getState())
> })
> 
> store.dispatch(cakeActions.ordered())
> store.dispatch(cakeActions.restocked(5))
> 
> store.dispatch(icecreamActions.buying())
> store.dispatch(icecreamActions.restocking(7))
> unsubscribe()
```

**Iceslice.js** here slice function is being made for icecream slice

```
const createSlice=require('@reduxjs/toolkit').createSlice
const initialState={
    no_of_icecream:10,
}
const icecreamSlice=createSlice({
    name:'icecream',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        buying:(state)=>{
            state.no_of_icecream--
        },
        restocking:(state,action)=>{
            state.no_of_icecream+=action.payload
        }
    }
})
module.exports=icecreamSlice.reducer
module.exports.icecreamActions=icecreamSlice.actions
```

**store.js** store function is being made where reducer are being imported

```
const cakeReducer= require('../feature/cake/cakeSlice')
const icecreamReducer=require('../feature/icecream/iceSlice')
const store=configureStore({
    reducer:{
        cake:cakeReducer,
        icecream:icecreamReducer,
    }
})
module.exports=store
```